# What exactly does aws instance network bandwidth refer to?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When browsing ec2 types, does network capacity refer to the bandwidth between amazon services, or to internet bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

Network bandwidth refers to the maximum network throughput of your EC2 instance. This is usually expressed in gigabits per second  (Gbit/s). This is the amount of data that can be transferred from your instance to its attached network, per second. Note some instance types have both Baseline and Burst bandwidth available.

Comment: What about internet bandwidth?

Comment: What do you mean by internet bandwidth  exactly?

Comment: bandwidth to endpoints outside of the amazon realm. If i were to go to google.com for example, or transfer a file via ftp to a client, or serve a web page to a client.

Comment: For data transfer rates out to the internet well... it depends. Depends on the network capacity at a given service endpoint, and all of the networking latency in between. It's a different metric.